# Выполнение поиска, отображение найденных, спаривание, подключение bluetooth устройств на Android MAUI C# 8

Tags: android, maui, c#-8.0

Как выполнить поиск устройств, отображение списка НАЙДЕННЫХ (не сопряженных) устройства, сопряжение и подключение к устройствам через bluetooth на смартфонах Android с использование MAUI и C# 8 (использование библиотек нежелательно, так как хотел бы хорошо разобраться в работе Bluetooth)?
Суть приложение такова: включить блютуз, запустить обнаружение устройств, при обнаружении каких либо устройств отображать их на экране смартфона, выполнять сопряжение с выбранным пользователем устройством, подключение к эту устройству и обмен с ним данными.
Желательно либо подробную статью об использовании всех этих операций в MAUI, C#8 либо описать подробно с примерами!

P.S. все разрешения касательно bluetooth включены в файле манифеста. Все выполняется в отдельной библиотеке классов Maui.
Содержание файла манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-sdk />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

_bleAdapter.StartDiscovery(); - всегда возвращает false.
_bleAdapter.BondedDevices; - отображает, что очевидно, список только сопряженных устройств

Comment: Как пишут в Андроид документации по методу `startDiscovery()` -- "If Bluetooth state is not STATE_ON, this API will return false". Начтите с этого.